# Sound card driver not detected on Linux Mint 19.1

Tags: audio, drivers, linux-mint, wine, alsa

This question may be a duplicate, but I have tried the suggestions given elsewhere to address this problem and nothing has helped.

Here is my system info:

```
System:    Host: justin-Z97M-D3H Kernel: 4.15.0-20-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 7.3.0 
       Desktop: Cinnamon 4.0.8 wm: muffin dm: LightDM Distro: Linux Mint 19.1 Tessa 
       base: Ubuntu 18.04 bionic 
Machine:   Type: Desktop Mobo: Gigabyte model: Z97M-D3H v: x.x serial: <filter> 
       BIOS: American Megatrends v: F4 date: 05/15/2014 
CPU:       Topology: Quad Core model: Intel Core i5-4460 bits: 64 type: MCP arch: Haswell rev: 3 
       L2 cache: 6144 KiB 
       flags: lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 25600 
       Speed: 1200 MHz min/max: 800/3400 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 1109 2: 1109 3: 1116 
       4: 1112 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics 
       vendor: Gigabyte driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 chip ID: 8086:0412 
       Device-2: NVIDIA GM107 [GeForce GTX 750 Ti] vendor: ASUSTeK driver: nvidia v: 390.116 
       bus ID: 01:00.0 chip ID: 10de:1380 
       Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.19.6 driver: modesetting,nvidia 
       unloaded: fbdev,nouveau,vesa resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
       OpenGL: renderer: GeForce GTX 750 Ti/PCIe/SSE2 v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 390.116 
       direct render: Yes 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio driver: N/A 
       bus ID: 00:03.0 chip ID: 8086:0c0c 
       Device-2: Intel 9 Series Family HD Audio vendor: Gigabyte driver: N/A bus ID: 00:1b.0 
       chip ID: 8086:8ca0 
       Device-3: NVIDIA vendor: ASUSTeK driver: N/A bus ID: 01:00.1 chip ID: 10de:0fbc 
       Sound Server: ALSA v: k4.15.0-20-generic
```

What happened originally was that I tried to install Wine-4.3 from source, and when I did that, the configure script told me that I needed to install OSSv4 for my Windows applications to have sound. After I did this, my speakers stopped working, and when I looked in sound settings, only the dummy output was visible. When I checked my ALSA information (http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=5b154d6c7cf30ee77c0eaf85ac857da3e7330ef8
) it showed that there was no driver detected for my sound card. I looked for compatible drivers on the ALSA  Project site, but all of the links to those drivers were broken. Any suggestions for how to fix this would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should absolutely avoid installing from source, particularly drivers. OSS probably took over your audio and messed up completely your system. You'd probably better be reinstalling entirely Mint after backing up your home directory.

Comment: Was sound even working before?

Comment: It was working before. After I installed OSSv4, it suddenly stopped.  Other than simply reinstalling Mint and starting over, is there a way to safely clear OSSv4 and get ALSA back in working order? I have already tried all other methods I could find.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Sorry for the silence. Yes, I had to reinstall Mint 19.1, but I got my sound system back in working order.